# Is a child believed (neman) for halachos in regards to himself?

Tags: minor-katan-child, trust-neemanut

I will pick 2 examples however I don't have any makoros at the moment (so please help to provide or correct me/help edit.)

If a katan (child) is not neman (believed) in regards to tovelling celim for someone. Would he be believed in regards to using celim (vessels) that he tovelled. That is if his parents came along and saw him eating from a certain cli and the parent asked "was that tovelled" and they responded "yes" do we believe the katan? Or is it better to give him a cli that we for sure know was tovelled?

What about if the katan was eating food that need to be checked for bugs and we asked him "did you check that food" and he respods "yes". Can we believe him or better to give him food that we know for sure was checked.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're asking if a child is an 'Eid Ehad.

Comment: @SethJ for himself. Not that others would use the cli or eat the food. Only for him (that the parents wouldn't need to give him a new cli or check the food, etc.) That's the question

Comment: @Yehoshua You can ask it stronger. Can he use the Kli when he grows up?

Comment: @DoubleAA I could ask that. But that's too strong for now. Let's work out this first! Feel free to edit the question

Comment: @Double AA, The answer I think he is believed when he grows up as well and even for others. It is a gemoro in second perek kesubos. A mishna there.

Comment: @shulem if you have an answer post it with complete sources

Comment: @Yehoshua He doesn't have an answer because those sources don't discuss your question. It's a related sugya, but not the same.

Comment: @Double AA why isnt it the same. It talks there about giving eidus of what they saw when they were young. Sounds the same to me.

Comment: @shulem It's talking about giving edus of a gadol to others. This question is asking about edus of a katan to himself.

Comment: It is talking about saying what he saw in his youth.

Comment: Is it weird that every time I see the word "believed", I keep reading it like it rhymes with בדיעבד?